# ONESHELL in Makefile not working with bash on Amazon Linux 2 ami

Tags: bash, makefile, amazon-ami, amazon-linux-2

I am using this Amazon Linux 2 AMI on an EC2 instance: `amazon/amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20210525.0-x86_64-gp2`

This Makefile works fine:

```
.SHELLFLAGS := -euo pipefail -c   
SHELL := bash

all:
    echo here
```

When I run `make all` I get:

```
bash-4.2$ make all
echo here
here
```

Then I add `.ONESHELL:` to the Makefile:

```
.ONESHELL:

.SHELLFLAGS := -euo pipefail -c   
SHELL := bash

all:
    echo here
```

Now when I run `make all` I get:

```
bash-4.2$ make all
echo here
bash: line 0: bash: echo here: invalid option name
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-koji-linux-gnu)
```

Make version:

```
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-koji-linux-gnu
```

If I remove the `.SHELLFLAGS` it will run successfully so it seems like a combination of the two is the problem. It also appears that with ONESHELL, the SHELLFLAGS are getting corrupted.

Comment: Don't know; that version of GNU make is quite old.  It works OK for me with the current version of GNU make.  Maybe try something newer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=35397) in make 3.82, fixed in 4.0. When both `.ONESHELL` and `.SHELLFLAGS` is used, the flags are not tokenized correctly.

You need to either drop one of the two or upgrade your `make` (possibly outside your distribution).